# How to get stored data on laravel filament relation manager after the record is stored in the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

So I want to get access to stored data on laravel filament relation manager but could not find any hint in the official docs.

In Filament Resource, we could easyly get the stored data in afterCreate via `$this->record`

```
protected function afterCreate(): void
{
    $this->record // stored record
}
```

But how do we do that in relation manager one? I could not find any hint about it in official docs v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the after hook on actions.

We have different types of actions in relation manager, like CRUD, Attach, and Associating.

Regardless of your actions in a relationship, you can use `after` hook on those actions and inject the model into the callback.

For example, if you have CRUD actions in your relation manager you can access the created model like the below:

```php
        return $table
            ->recordTitleAttribute('name')
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name'),
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                // ...
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make()->after(function (Product $product) {
                    dd($product);
                })
            ])
```

You can replace the product model with your own model or just use Laravel's abstract Model.

For `EditAction`, `AttachAction`, `AssociateAction`, ... you can do the same thing.